# How can I customize the list of Apps from the top right corner on Google's sites?

Tags: website

When I am on Google's home page, and I am signed into Gmail, there is an square icon with nine little squares atI the top right corner of the page.

If I click on it, I see the list of apps. I would like to customize the list of apps, but ironically Googling for this feature did not help.

Answer (score 0):

From my own Google searching, as of October 2013, you evidently cannot customize this. I'm guessing nothing has changed since then, I would expect them to make it obvious.

There is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-launcher-customizer-f/ponjkmladgjfjgllmhnkhgbgocdigcjm) to customize it. Not sure about options for other browsers.